# R - Use loop to cycle through a list of data frame names/columns

Tags: r, loops, variables

This line of code creates a vector from a data frame column which is used to generate quintile averages for plotting.

```
factorset <- r2na$ret_mom
```

i.e.

```
barplot(tapply(r2na$return1,cut(factorset, quantile(factorset, seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = .2))),mean),ann=F)
```

I would like to cycle through a list of data frame columns using a loop.

```
factorframes <- c("r2na$ret_mom", "r2na$ner_mom", "r2na$ln_peg", "ln_ftep_ratio", "r2na$gdp_gor_nxt_12m")

for (f in 1:length(factorframes)) {
factorset <- factorframes[i]
}
```

While I am sure the plotting could also be accomplished in single step, I am relatively new to R and first want to understand how the substitution works before getting to more complicated uses.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I am afraid your question isn't very clear and you didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) information on how to ask a good question. You can provide data for example by typing `dput(factorset)`. And indeed, your loop approach isn't very R-ish

Comment: Are you just asking how to get the names of a data.frame? That would be the `names` function if so. Just use `names(dt)` assuming `dt` is your data frame. Take a look at that and consider using a `for(name in names(dt))` kind of setup. Access each column in the for loop by doing `dt[, name]`.